# Simulate effective LEAD(1) or LEAD(2) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Assume i have a table with the dutch or english alfabet.

**Alfabet**

```
digit   
--------
a       
b       
c       
d       
e       
f       
g       
h       
i       
j       
k       
l       
m       
n       
o       
p       
q       
r       
s       
t       
x       
y       
z
```

Now i want to display a list like this.

```
digit   next_digit  next_two_digit  
------  ----------  ----------------
a       b           c               
b       c           d               
c       d           e               
d       e           f               
e       f           g               
f       g           h               
g       h           i               
h       i           j               
i       j           k               
j       k           l               
k       l           m               
l       m           n               
m       n           o               
n       o           p               
o       p           q               
p       q           r               
q       r           s               
r       s           t               
s       t           x               
t       x           y               
x       y           z               
y       z           (NULL)          
z       (NULL)      (NULL)
```

In Oracle (and more databases that support window functions) you can get this list with

```
SELECT 
   "digit"
 , LEAD("digit", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "digit" ASC) as next_digit   
 , LEAD("digit", 2) OVER (ORDER BY "digit" ASC) as next_two_digits
FROM 
 alfabet
ORDER BY 
 "digit" asc
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a11f1/4

Now i want to simulate the window function lead(1) and lead(2) in MySQL.

Now in MySQL i know i can get the same with co-related subqueries like so.

```
SELECT 
 *
 , (SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     alfabet alfabetInner 
    WHERE
      alfabetInner.digit > alfabet.digit     
    ORDER BY 
      digit ASC
    LIMIT 0, 1      
   ) AS next_digit

 , (SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     alfabet alfabetInner 
    WHERE
      alfabetInner.digit > alfabet.digit     
    ORDER BY 
      digit ASC
    LIMIT 1, 1      
   ) AS next_two_digit   
FROM 
 alfabet  
ORDER BY
 alfabet.digit ASC
```

**Editted because off comment from Evan Carroll**

> why doesn't the table Alfabet just store the id/row number on it?

Because i wanted to simulate a pure LEAD(1) or LEAD(2) solution without having to need a auto increment sequence without gaps as PRIMARY ID... the window function off Oracle doesnt do annything with a auto increment PRIMARY key also.

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a8701/2

> Now the question. Do you know even more (effective) LEAD simulation
>   methodes?

Comment: why doesn't the table Alfabet just store the id/row number on it?

Comment: @Evan Carroll because i wanted to simulate a pure LEAD(1) or LEAD(2) solution without having to need a auto increment sequence without gaps as PRIMARY ID... the window function off Oracle doesnt do annything with a auto increment PRIMARY key also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [MySQL 8, which supports Window Functions](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,654818,654818)
2. Hack around it..

   1. Generate a sequence of IDS. This whole project makes no sense without them anyway because the result set of a SQL query isn't guaranteed without an ORDER BY.
   2. LEFT-OUTER JOIN the table with itself self join on `id+1 = id`
3. MySQL specific, [emulate lag with user-defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316349/124486)

That [looks something like this in MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a8701/42),

```
SELECT t1.digit, t2.digit
FROM (
    SELECT digit, @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS id
    FROM
     alfabet  , (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
    ORDER BY
     alfabet.digit ASC
) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT digit, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS id
    FROM
     alfabet  , (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
    ORDER BY
     alfabet.digit ASC
) AS t2
  ON t1.id +1 = t2.id;
```

You can even make that simpler with

```
SELECT digit, previous
FROM (
    SELECT digit, @prev previous, @prev := digit AS prev
    FROM
     alfabet  , (SELECT @prev := '') r
    ORDER BY
     alfabet.digit ASC
) AS t1;
```